# How to capture multiline regex between two tags?

Tags: regex

What's the best way to select all text between 2 comment tags? E.g.

```
<!-- Text 1
     Text 2
     Text 3
-->
```

`<\!--.*` will capture `<!-- Text 1` but not `Text 2`, `Text 3`, or `-->`

**Edit**
As per Basti M's answer, `<\!--((?:.*\n)*)-->` will select everything between the **first** `<!--` and **last** `-->`. I.e. lines 1 to 11 below.

How would I modify this to select just lines within separate tags? i.e. lines 1 to 4:

```
1 <!-- Text 1 //First
2      Text 2
3      Text 3
4 -->
5
6 More text
7 
8 <!-- Text 4
9      Text 5
10     Text 6
11 -->         //Last
```

Comment: Please provide your regex flavor, some are multiline by default, some not.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/78845

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depending on your underlying engine use the `s`-modifier (and add `-->` at the end of your expression.
This will make the `.` match newline-characters aswell.

If the `s`-flag is not available to you, you may use

```
<!--((?:.*\r?\n?)*)-->
```

Explanation:

```
<!--         #start of comment
  (           #start of capturing group
    (?:       #start of non-capturing group
      .*\r?\n? #match every character including a line-break
    )*        #end of non-capturing group, repeated between zero and unlimited times
  )           #end of capturing group
-->           #end of comment
```

To match multiple comment blocks you can use

```
/(?:<!--((?:.*?\r?\n?)*)-->)+/g
```

[Demo @ Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/qP2wA0)

Comment: This assumes that `-->` only ever occurs right after a `\n`. Also, no need to escape the `!`.

Comment: Thanks, this works but not if there are two or more comment tags on the same page (it selects everything between the first opener and last closing). How can I modify it to only select the next closing tag?

Comment: @alias51 add `?` after `*` to make it reluctant

Comment: @alias51 added another expression for multiple comment blocks

Comment: @BastiM Thanks, if I dont have access to the s- flag, is there an alternative? (I am using sublime text)

Comment: regex is not the right tool here, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags like Johnsyweb said.

Comment: @alias51 oh, in the last case you don't have to use the `s`-flag, forgot about that

Comment: @sputnick this is absolutely right, but the OP asked specifically for a regex

Answer (score 3):

Use the `s` modifier to match new lines. E.g.:

```
/<!--(.*)-->/s
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/lH0jK9

Comment: Should probably use `.*?` to make it non-greedy.

Answer (score 1):

[Regex is not the right tool to parse html or xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), use a proper parser, I use [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) here :

```
$ cat file.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<test>
<!-- Text 1
     Text 2
     Text 3
-->
</test>
```

The test :

```
$ xmllint --xpath '/test/comment()' file.xml
<!-- Text 1
     Text 2
     Text 3
-->
```

If you parse html, use the `--html` switch.